# How to get minimum BST element?

Tags: rust, binary-search-tree

Given this BST struct:

```
pub enum BST{
    Nil,
    Node{
        k: i32,
        l: Box<BST>,
        r: Box<BST>,
    }
}
```

How can a function be programmed such that it gives the minimum element of the BST?

I tried some things, my latest attempt is:

```
fn min(&mut self) -> &mut BST{
        match self {
            BST::Nil => self,
            BST::Node{ l, ..} =>
                match **l {
                    BST::Nil => self,
                    BST::Node{..} => l.min(),
                }
        }
}
```

however this doesnt work, the purpose of the min function is to work on BST deletions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a function which takes and returns a mutable borrow is very restrictive; roughly speaking, anything you return — by match or by function call — can never *stop* being borrowed within that scope, even if you don't actually return it, which is a problem for your function because you want to inspect the tree and then possibly return `self` *instead of* a component of `self`. I tried a few possibilities and came up with this version which the compiler accepts:

```rust
impl BST {
    fn min(&mut self) -> &mut BST {
        match self {
            BST::Nil => self,
            BST::Node { l, .. } if matches!(**l, BST::Nil) => self,
            BST::Node { l, .. } => l.min(),
        }
    }
}
```

I think the key element that makes this borrow-checker-friendly is that there are two completely separate match arms (and thus separate patterns) for the two `Node` possibilities: in the second arm, `l` is temporary, and in the third arm, `l` is returned (with modification by `.min()`), but these two cases have separate bindings for `l` and thus they can have different lifetimes.

(It's a little silly to write `matches!` inside a [match guard](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/guard.html), but we can't actually write a single pattern because of the `Box`; if [`box_patterns`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/unstable-book/language-features/box-patterns.html) becomes a stable feature then we'll be able to write a single pattern like `BST::Node { l: box BST::Nil, .. }`.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to solve this is to break down your problem into simpler steps. I.e. instead of doing two matches at once, you could only do a single one at a time, this way it also compiles:

```rust
pub enum BST {
    Nil,
    Node { k: i32, l: Box<BST>, r: Box<BST> },
}

impl BST {
    fn min(&mut self) -> &mut BST {
        match self {
            BST::Nil => self,
            BST::Node { l, .. } => l.min(),
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** Actually, as @Kevin Reid noticed this changes the semantics of the code, because the second match in OP returned `self` instead of `l`.

In my opinion, this makes the function inconsistent, because you either want the minimum element (with is actually is always `Nil` or the `Node` before it, which would make the `self` in the outer match invalid, should be a `panic!` instead).

However, if you want to get the `Node` before the minimal element (that would be `Nil`), you should go around this special case of returning a `Nil` if called on a `Nil`. In my opinion, this can be best reflected in the type system by restructuring the `BST` type like in the following. Here, `min_node` returns always the "node" which has a "nil" (i.e. `None`) in `l`, however, the user can only create "nodes":

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct BstNode {
    k: i32,
    l: Option<Box<BstNode>>,
    r: Option<Box<BstNode>>,
}

impl BstNode {
    fn min_node(&mut self) -> &mut BstNode {
        if let Some(ref mut l) = self.l {
            l.min_node()
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This function is not the same as the original function's behavior-if-it-would-compile: it always returns a reference to a `Nil` variant, whereas the original would return a `Node` if one exists (the nested match returns `self` rather than `l`).

Comment: @KevinReid You are right, I missed that. I updated my answer to include the use-case of OP.